# Tkinter adding entry values to list through a loop

Tags: tkinter

When I try to add the value of tkinter entry boxes created in a loop to a list, it gives me the result - `<tkinter.Entry object .!entry>` for every entry box value, rather than the actual value of the entry box inputted. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet answers your question.

Use `bind` to link your `Entry` widget to Return key press and function `answer`.

Then use method `get` on the widget connected to Return key press to extract the contents of the `Entry` widget.

```py
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

def answer( ev ):
    print(ev.widget.get())

for a in range( 4 ):
    e = tk.Entry(master, font = "Helvetica 14 normal")
    e.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
    e.bind("<Return>", answer)

e.focus()

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, @Derek. The logic behind what you said makes sense and should solve my issue. I also realised the values were being stored but were displaying as entry objects. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Good one @Kane_Iskra. Happy coding.